# Get total amount of SQL rows retrieved by Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

**Context**

I'm working on an project where we perform very large nested queries using Sequelize.
Our server is crashing due to the gigantic amount of data Sequelize has to parse. (*JavaScript heap out of memory*)

I'd like to implement a hook throwing a warning whenever the amount of SQL rows retrieved exceed a given limit.

The amount of SQL rows is different from `Model.count()`, it should take associations into consideration.

It's the amount of rows retrieved by the SQL query outside of Sequelize.

Node: 18.12.1
Sequelize: 6.6.5
Postgres: 11.14

**Question**

Is there a way to get the total amount of actual SQL rows retrieved by Sequelize?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with large databases, if you just want the number of rows retrieved, it would be better if you do that counting calculation in the database directly than moving those rows to your javascript. But if you really want all the data which it selects, I would suggest you not do it in one go but rather collect the data from the database in batches. If this query is pretty much static, then you can create a view in the database and then get the data from there bit by bit so that your ram won't get filled up. I hope this helps, although I cannot help you with a direct code as I don't do javascript or sequelize.

I found a code from [docs of sequelize](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/) and here they have showed an example of using a count() of postgres in javascript.

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'foo',
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('hats')), 'n_hats'],
    'bar'
  ]
});
```

which roughly translates to the sql statement

```
SELECT foo, COUNT(hats) AS n_hats, bar FROM ...
```

I hope this helps.